# Making Custom Posts behave like pages

Tags: custom-post-types

i am currently working on a theme, within this theme i would like to have posts which have parent and child posts. Within this theme I have currently created a post type called "associations". In a way i would like to create a microsite using posts and their hierarchal structure. These posts must also belong to custom taxonomy terms as well. The structure would be like:

**Association landing page**
-Super cool association name (parent post) (taxonomy term: dentists)

- Contact (child post)
- history (child post)
- tips    (child post)

I would like all the permalinks of the child pages to display wether the user is on the (parent post) or any of its (child posts)

I currently have this code but it only displays the children of the post on the parent single-associations.php

```
<?php
    // setup your arguments: 
    $args = array(
        // We want to call all posts the custom post type 'help'
        'post_type' => 'associations',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        // Next, we want to see if the current post is a parent of any help posts
        'post_parent' => $post->ID
    );
    // We then pass these to a wordpress query, and setup our loop
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php if ($loop->have_posts()) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <!-- This post has children, so we'll list them out -->
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <!-- This post has no children -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to have a custom template for each of the child posts as well.

I registered the custom post and made sure the 
hierarchical was set to true.

```
'hierarchical'          => true,
```

in order to get the page attributes of the post I also made sure that the post type supported page attributes.

```
'supports'              => array( 'title', 'thumbnail','editor','page-attributes',),
```

I also registered  a taxonomy and inputed multiple terms.

This so far has allowed me to be able to create a parent-child relationship much like the pages in wordpress. But i need some guidance on understanding wether or not this is the most effective way to achieve this sort of setup. if anyone has any ideas on how to improve this method or a suggestion on how to achieve what i want i would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Hi - welcome - lots of good information but I'm not quite clear what the exact question is.

Comment: hi @AndyMacaulay-Brook I would essentially like to have my custom post type behave like pages. in my theme i would like to have a section that displays all of these associations, once the user clicks on one, i would like it to go to the parent post (association landing page). this parent post will be titled the name of the association. This parent post will have a series of child posts. like association contact information association history etc. but i would like for the slugs to read www.sitename/associationlandingpage/contact. I appreciate it

Comment: I think you'd be better off just using pages. CPTs work well for items that have a common information structure like products (with prices, SKUs and so on) but I don't see the need here.

Comment: hey @AndyMacaulay-Brook I have to be able to list all the association parent pages with the ability to search them. How would i group the pages globally? I know taxonomy is not the best practice with pages right? The reason is so i could only list the association pages wp_list_pages does not have the ability to only list pages that are associations.

Comment: Try the child_of argument.